# How to access the ServletContext in resources.groovy for Grails 3?

Tags: spring, servlets, grails

I need to define several beans for spring and to configure the beans I need access to the ServletContext.  Previously in Grails 2.x we had code like

```
beans = {
    ...
    dataProvider(DataProvider) {
        def context = ServletContextHolder.getServletContext()
        // use context to configure this bean
    }
    ...
}
```

However in grails 3.x (3.1.10 to be specific), the context variable is always null.  If there is another place other than the `resources.groovy` file that will accomplish this, then that's fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
def context = application.mainContext.servletContext
```